# How to use msbuild to generate a VS .sln file where everything is on x64 platform?

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2017

When I build my project in command line, everything works fine. But when I tried to generate a `.sln` file for the project by running `msbuild /t:SlnGen /p:Platform=x64`
at the command prompt, and then click `build` in VS (debug, x64), I got an error saying it can't copy a dependent binary folder because it is not found. Since my project is on `CBT`, I have x64, x86 and Any-CPU platform settings. My project used to be built on `CoreXT`. My suspicion is `VS` build doesn't handle the output path of the dependencies correctly.

Then how can I build the solution only on `x64` through `VS`?

Any hint will be very helpful!

Comment: `My suspicion is VS build doesn't handle the output path of the dependencies correctly.` VS use solution file to manage projects, use project file to manage the whole structure for one project. The solution file and project file have default format, I never used the SlnGen target and I haven't heard about it, can you share some details about the original project file you have, and the content of generated .sln file. Or a simple sample to reproduce this issue. I'm not sure if the generated .sln file or the original .csproj file can cause this issue.

Comment: Thank you for your analysis. @LanceLi-MSFT Here I found a useful method which works well on my case: [StackOverflow]( https://stackoverflow.microsoft.com/questions/19532/how-do-i-default-slngen-to-x64).

Comment: Hi YuShu, any update for this issue? If you've found the workaround for this issue, you can write the answer with your useful info and approach, then members with similar issue can benefit from that :) (See [answer own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)).

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT I found a workaround and put it in the comment. :)

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT Now I got you. Thank you for the suggestion. :)